# How to remove sequence of characters from string

Tags: c#, string

I want to remove an unknown number of character sequences B from a given string A.
The removing must start to the right of the position of a character sequence C. The removing must stop when the B character sequence ends.

Example for string A:

```
xxxxxxxxBxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxCBBBBBByyyyyyyyyByyyy

A ... sequence of characters from which B's that follow C must be removed
C ... a sequence of characters (example: 123)
B ... a sequence of characters (example: vbz)
x and y ... any characters
```

In this example all B's after C must be removed. All other B's must not be removed.

The result would be:

```
xxxxxxxxBxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxCyyyyyyyyyByyyy
```

I tried to use:

```
A = A.replace("vbz","");
```

but that removes every 'vbz' sequence from A.
How can I exclude the removal of those 'vbz' that are not preceeded by C?

Regards, Manu

Comment: The string class has plenty of helper methods such as IndexOf and Split, LastIndexOf.   Start first by splitting the string into smaller parts, pass those parts into the next function which finds the termination sequence and passes it to the next function after splitting, repeat until done.  Also, look into LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try this?

```
var.Replace("x", "");
var.Replace("y", "");
```

Just replace `x` and `y` with the unknown string sequence

Comment: The snippet may suggest incorrectly that `Replace` is a static method (`string` is a reserved word) and that it mutates the string it's called on.

Answer (score 1):

```
string A = "xxxxxxxxBxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxCBBBBBByyyyyyyyyByyyy";
string pattern = @"(?<=C)[B]*";
string B = Regex.Replace(A, pattern, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
As per your requirement, 2 conditions need to be satisfied for removing from a string :

1. unknown number of string sequences B
2. The removing must start to the right of the position of a string C

It can be achieved using Regex class of System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace.

string A = "xxxxxxxxBxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxCBBBBBByyyyyyyyyByyyy";
string pattern = "(?<=C)[b]*";
string result = Regex.Replace(A, pattern,"",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);


Note :
pattern variable contains regex pattern.
(cb*) : 
() : defines group of characters
c : starting string
b : B or b ; i.e, need to be replaced or removed
* : defines multiple number of characters defines before *
(?<=c) : Match any position following a prefix "c"
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase : it says the removed character can be any case like B or b
```